TimeLine Plot of Every Historical Country/Empire - how to control y axis
tl;dr - how do I control the y axis of the timelineplot such that I might get the same location to appear at the same level?

I'm trying to see if Mathematica can make a similar timeline to this. Specifically, note that the y axis of the graphic is based on current countries. I'd like to make a Timelineplot where I can control the y axis of each datapoint (or datalength for the timelineplot).

I've made the beginning of an attempt using Mathematica's "HistoricalCountry" entities. I'm struggling with the vertical alignment and how to control that in the timeline plot.
allhistoricalcountries = EntityList["HistoricalCountry"];

polygonhistoricalcountires = 
  EntityClass["HistoricalCountry", "HasPolygon" -> True] // EntityList;

ProgressIndicator[
 Dynamic[i], {i, 1, Length[polygonhistoricalcountires]}]
timelinedata = 
  Table[{polygonhistoricalcountires[[i]]["FullName"], 
    DateInterval[{polygonhistoricalcountires[[i]]["StartDate"], 
      polygonhistoricalcountires[[i]]["EndDate"]}], 
    Area[polygonhistoricalcountires[[i]]["Polygon"]], 
    GeoIdentify["Continent", 
      polygonhistoricalcountires[[i]]["Position"]][[1]]}, {i, 
    (* you might want this to be a small number for testing *) Length[polygonhistoricalcountires]}];

The above code grabs all the historical countries data. This then gets rid of the bogus dates and geopolygons
(* check is date *) 
totest = DateBounds[#] & /@ timelinedata[[;; , 2]];
tests = Position[
   DateObjectQ[#[[1]]] == True && DateObjectQ[#[[2]]] == True & /@ 
    totest, False];
timelinedata = Delete[timelinedata, tests];
(* check if number for area *) 
tests = Position[
  NumberQ[QuantityMagnitude[#]] & /@ timelinedata[[;; , 3]], False]
timelinedata = Delete[timelinedata, tests];

continentgrouping = GroupBy[timelinedata, Last];

Group by continent:
getplotdata[continent_, continentgrouping_, scale_] := 
 Module[{groupingthickness, grouping}, 
  grouping =  (continent /. {continentgrouping})[[;; , ;; , 2]][[1]];
  groupingthickness = (continent /. {continentgrouping})[[;; , ;; , 
      3]][[1]];
  groupingthickness = (QuantityMagnitude[#] & /@ groupingthickness);
  groupingthickness = scale*groupingthickness/Max[groupingthickness];
  Return[{grouping, groupingthickness}];
  ]

toplot = 
  getplotdata[#, continentgrouping, 1] & /@ {Entity[
     "GeographicRegion", "Asia"], 
    Entity["GeographicRegion", "SouthAmerica"], 
    Entity["GeographicRegion", "NorthAmerica"], 
    Entity["GeographicRegion", "Europe"], 
    Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"], 
    Entity["GeographicRegion", "Australia"]};
TimelinePlot[{toplot[[1, 1]], toplot[[2, 1]], toplot[[3, 1]], 
  toplot[[4, 1]], toplot[[5, 1]]}]


Now I add in thicknesses which are scaled by the magnitude of the GeoPolygon - but how would I get them to align with current countries? Or rather, how do I control the y axis of the timelineplot such that I might get the same location to appear at the same level?
thicknessesasisa = 
  Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[#]] & /@ toplot[[1, 2]];
thicknessessouthamerica = 
  Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[#]] & /@ toplot[[2, 2]];
thicknessesnorthamerica = 
  Directive[Green, AbsoluteThickness[#]] & /@ toplot[[3, 2]];
thicknesseseurope = 
  Directive[Yellow, AbsoluteThickness[#]] & /@ toplot[[4, 2]];
thicknessesafrica = 
  Directive[Orange, AbsoluteThickness[#]] & /@ toplot[[5, 2]];

thicknesses = 
  Flatten[{thicknessesasisa, thicknessessouthamerica, 
    thicknessesnorthamerica, thicknesseseurope, thicknessesafrica}, 1];
plottingdata = {#} & /@ 
   Flatten[{toplot[[1, 1]], toplot[[2, 1]], toplot[[3, 1]], 
     toplot[[4, 1]], toplot[[5, 1]]}];
TimelinePlot[plottingdata, PlotStyle -> thicknesses]


